# Java: Why is my program only running 9 times instead of 1000 (for and while loops)?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while, tic-tac-toe

In my program, I am trying to simulate 1000 games of randomized tic tac toe.  The game is only being played nine times, probably due to the inner nested do-while loop.  I;m not sure how to fix this, I have tried changing the inner do-while loop to a while loop, and the outer for loop to a while loop.  I know it is probably a simple mistake, but I can't pinpoint where the mistake lies.  Below is my code for these two loops.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
for (count = 0; count < 1001; count++) {
    int movecount = 0; 
    int row, col;
    int player = 1;
    do {
        //pick a row
        row = r.nextInt(3);
        //pick a col
        col = r.nextInt(3);
        //check if spot is empty
        if (list[row][col]>0) {continue;}
        //if empty, move current player there, add to count
        list[row][col] = player;
        if (CheckRowWin(player, list)) {
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " won");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tie Game");
        }
        movecount++;
        //switch player turn
        player = 3 - player;

    } while (movecount < 9);
    }
```

Comment: at some point `list` is going to fill up and you'll simply `continue` that inner loop and skip over everythign else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer loop *is* running 1001 times, it just doesn't appear to because there's nothing else in your outer loop aside from the `do{}while()` which is running only nine times and printing out stuff.

```
for (count = 0; count < 1001; count++) {
    int movecount = 0; 
    int row, col;
    int player = 1;
    do {
        //pick a row
        row = r.nextInt(3);
        //pick a col
        col = r.nextInt(3);
        //check if spot is empty
        if (list[row][col]>0) {continue;}
        //if empty, move current player there, add to count
        list[row][col] = player;
        if (CheckRowWin(player, list)) {
            System.out.println("Player " + player + " won");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tie Game");
        }
        movecount++;
        //switch player turn
        player = 3 - player;

    } while (movecount < 9);
    // don't forget to reset movecount
    // so that the inner loop will run again
    movecount = 0;
    // clear the "board" for the next game
    // note: using two nested loops is slow and inefficient
    // but it goes along with the theme of learning loops
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            list[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't his outer loop looping 1001 times? from 0 to 1000 included.

Comment: The console is still only returning nine results for some reason.

Comment: I noticed this: `if (list[row][col]>0) {continue;}` is skipping if the board isn't cleared. You'll need to clear the board along with setting `movecount = 0;`.

Comment: I tried to clear the board by adding `row = 0; col = 0;`  right under the `movecount = 0;` line of code.  This does not seem to iterate the game 1000 times however.

Comment: No, you have to clear each cell of `list` not just the `row` and `col` indexes.